# Confused about RequireJS dependency

Tags: javascript, dependencies, requirejs

I am trying to wrap my head around dependencies in requirejs.

1. If I already declared dependencies for a file using `shim`, do I need to re-declare it when I define the module in that file?
2. If I use `require` to load dependencies such as backbone, do I need to re-declare it when I define a module that is loaded as part of `require`?

Here's my code so far:

```
require.config({
    //alias
    paths: {
        Backbone: 'libs/backbone-min',
        Config: 'config',
        Dom: 'dom',
        App: 'app'
    },

    //dependencies
    shim: {
        'Backbone': ['libs/underscore-min'],
        'Dom': ['libs/sizzle']
    }
});

//used to load and use stuff
require(['Config','Dom','App','Backbone'], function(){

});
```

So in `dom.js` can I just define a module using `define(function(){...});` and start using Sizzle? Or do I still need to define it like this `define(['libs/sizzle'], function(){...});`

Also if I define a module in app.js, do I still need to load backbone in `define`, since I already included it as part of `require()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) If I already declared dependencies for a file using shim, do I need
>   to re-declare it when I define the module in that file?

For every module you need to define it's set of dependencies.

> 2) If I use require to load dependencies such as backbone, do I need
>   to re-declare it when I define a module that is loaded as part of
>   require?

If you want to use backbone as dependency in arbitary modyle you could write

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) { .. }
```

Comment: so basically `Shim` simply loads the files in a specific order and `require()` loads the files and do not interact with the modules

Comment: The best answer on question what Shim actually does was given by RequireJS creator James Burke. You can read that message on following url: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/-han0L_Sv_E/iFttMxDkT1UJ